# Is there a way to sync file naming across environments?

Tags: version-control

I have 3 environments with version control. Dev, staging and production.

Now, say I create a new node in staging and create a corresponding file with the name: page--node--28.html.twig

On production environment users keep posting articles, so it will already have a node 28 which messes up the version control.

Is there any way to manage this seamlessly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do not use node ID based templates at all in such scenarios. Instead create your own custom theme suggestions based on a logic that does not change between environments:

```
function THEME_NAME_theme_suggestions_page_alter(array &$suggestions, array $variables) {

  if ($node = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameter('node')) {
    $my_suggestion = $node->getSomethingThatWorksEverywhere();
    $suggestions[] = 'page__' . $my_suggestion;
  }
}
```

Comment: This is perfect, thank you. Also, while we are here, is there a way to migrate structural changes across environments like adding a new field in content type? Or should I ask this as a separate question?

Comment: TL,DR: `drush config:export && git push` on dev and `git pull && drush config:import` on prod - google for "drupal configuration management" and you will find a lot on this topic

Comment: Note: drush config:import will import/overwrite the complete site config, not incrementally add single configs